# Request failed with status code 419 Laravel Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

This code is related to my login page. I'm using Laravel and Vue.js, and when I try to log in, I encounter 419 error.

```
<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

import axios from 'axios'

    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
    
    import { authStore } from '../stores/authstore'
    
    const router = useRouter();
    const useAuth = authStore();
    
    const form = ref({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });
    const submitLogin = async () => {
        await useAuth.getToken();
        await axios.post('/login',
            {
                email: form.value.email,
                password: form.value.password
            });
        router.push('/');
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Add this line at the bottom of your ```bootstrap.js```: ```axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')```

Comment: login is postroute and post route should use @csrf

Comment: It would be prudent to include the code for your login route if you're having problems with it... Also, what debugging have you done?  What other [solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+419) have you tried?